# How to make the video in view pager stop playing when the next page is scrolled?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

First, I play a `video` in the first `view pager`, then when i scroll to the next page, the `video` continues to playing. The video stops when i come to the third page. Is it any coding to stop the `video` or the activity by the time I scroll to the next page? Eager for expert help!!!

**Below is my MainActivity which has the viewPager and FragmentPageAdapter**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
    List<Fragment> fragmentList;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    int passPosition = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);

        passPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",-1);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,arrayList);
        fragmentList = addItem();
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragmentList);
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        vpPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeOutTransformer());
        if(passPosition != -1){
            vpPager.setCurrentItem(passPosition);
        }
    }

    private List<Fragment> addItem(){
        fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        arrayList.add(new Item("a",0,0));
        fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance("a"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("b",0,0));
        fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance("b"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("c",0,0));
        fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance("c"));
        arrayList.add(new Item("d",0,0));
        fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance("d"));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"add successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return fragmentList;
    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> fragmentList;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragmentList.size();
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           Fragment fm;
            fm = this.fragmentList.get(position);

            return fm;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Pag " + position;
        }
    }
}
```

**2.Below is my Fragment1 where has the videoView**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
    private VideoView videoView;

    public static final Fragment1 newInstance(String message)
    {
        Fragment1 f = new Fragment1();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    /*@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        text = getArguments().getString("someInt");
        //title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }*/

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        textView.setText(message);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video));
        videoView.stopPlayback();
        getVideo();
        return view;
    }
    public void getVideo(){
        videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                videoView.start();
                return true;
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Picture1 : Video played in first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJe4T.png)

[Picture2 : when i swipe to 2nd page, the video is still playing and visible! Why???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHr8R.png)

Comment: show what you tried.

Comment: Please provide us some code you have tried so that we can help you Eagerly :)

Comment: Hi Vincent, have you found the solution of this problem?

Comment: @DäñishShärmà no eventually